# How can I extract DNA sequence using a Perl script from UCSC if I have their coordinates?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

How can I extract DNA sequence using a Perl script from genome browser (UCSC), if I have their coordinates?

Comment: http://biostar.stackexchange.com may be a better place...

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe a [DAS sequence request](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQdownloads.html#download23) into a Perl script that parses out the XML element containing the sequence.

For example, the following is a `curl` request of UCSC's DAS server, throwing away the standard error, piped to `parseSeq.pl`:

```
$ curl http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/hg19/dna?segment=1:10000,10999 2>/dev/null | parseSeq.pl
```

The output of `curl` will be an XML document containing the 1000-base DNA sequence from the `hg19` assembly of the human genome. The request asks for base 10000 to 10999 (remember that UCSC is [0-based](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQtracks.html#tracks1)) from the first chromosome. The XML will include some other stuff useful for logging and error checking.

After piping XML into a Perl script, you can use Perl's [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) module to quickly parse out the stuff you want.

To help you get started, your `parseSeq.pl` file might start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
use XML::Simple;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
use Data::Dumper;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

my $xml = new XML::Simple;                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
my $ref = $xml->XMLin('-');                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

print Dumper $ref;
```

The output of this should give you enough of a start to pull the DNA sequence from `$ref`.